# UML Relationship Type: Variables & Parameters & Cloning

Tags: java, class, dependencies, uml, aggregation

In a UML Diagram, what would be the relationship for these scenarios?

`1. Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There are methods in Class A such as:
   public function (ArrayList<B>)
   public function2 (): ArrayList<B>`

`2. Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There are methods in Class A such as:
   public function (ArrayList<B>)
   public function2 (B)`

`3. Take 1 class, class A. There are methods in Class A to clone itself by using details of the parent, such as:
   public clone (): A
   public A (A parent)
   Is there a relationship line in the UML to itself?`

`4. Take 2 classes, class C and class D. Class D is an aggregate of class C (C has D). Class D however has a clone function in the same way as Q3 above. Does this mean Class D is not composed of class C?`

`5. Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There is a method in Class A which have variables that create ArrayList<B>.`

My thoughts on each of the scenarios (however I'm very unsure)

1. class A uses class B (dependency) [although I'm tossing up between this and association]
2. class A uses class B (dependency)
3. Yes, class A uses class A (dependency)
4. No, Class D is still composed of Class C
5. class A has class B (aggregation)

Am I completely wrong in my understanding? What is the correct relationship in those scenarios?

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There are methods in Class A such as: public function (ArrayList) public function2 (): ArrayList
> class A uses class B (dependency) [although I'm tossing up between this and association]
> ```

If ArrayList is made up of instances of B, than it's dependency A-->B. If there is a data member of type B in A, that it would be an association (in one of its variations).

The difference is that a dependency is more generic and depicts a weak, typically short time connection between those two (like here, method parameters of type B in A). Association means a stronger and longer lasting relationship, expressed through a data member on the code level.

> ```
> Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There are methods in Class A such as: public function (ArrayList) public function2 (B)
> class A uses class B (dependency)
> ```

The same case as before, here is clear that B is a method parameter.

> ```
> Take 1 class, class A. There are methods in Class A to clone itself by using details of the parent, such as: public clone (): A
> ```
>
> public A (A parent) Is there a relationship line in the UML to itself?
>       Yes, class A uses class A (dependency)

If class A has a data member of class A of its array, that it's a circular association to itself. If not, there is no need to put a dependency A-->A. A depends on itself anyway, so it would be redundant.

> Take 2 classes, class C and class D. Class D is an aggregate of
>   class C (C has D). Class D however has a clone function in the same
>   way as Q3 above. Does this mean Class D is not composed of class C?
>       No, Class D is still composed of Class C

It is.

> ```
> Take 2 classes, class A and class B. There is a method in Class A which have variables that create ArrayList.
> class A has class B (aggregation)
> ```

No, unless there is also a data member of B in A, it is just another case of dependency, as the link is temporal and short lasting (during the method execution)

Comment: Thanks Aleks. I didn't realise my `<B>` disappeared (I've put them in code blocks so they stay), but the answers cover the situations with it there. Very helpful answer